# Creature training Dynamic Programming on TopCoder

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have been trying to solve [the following TopCoder problem](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=8570&rd=12012&rm=269199&cr=7581406):

> You are playing a strategy game and you wish to train the strongest army for the final fight. There are creatures of N levels in the game, numbered from 0 to N-1, inclusive. You already have some creatures in your army and D days to train them. The number of creatures you have is given in a int[] count. It contains N elements and its i-th element is the number of creatures of level i.
>
> During each day, you can choose one creature and train it. Training increases a creature's level by 1, i.e., a creature of level 0 becomes a creature of level 1, a creature of level 1 becomes a creature of level 2, and so on. The only exception is creatures of level N-1 - such creatures can't be trained as N-1 is the largest possible level. You can train the same creature during more than one day. For example, if you train a creature during 3 days, it will gain 3 levels. You can also skip days and not train any creatures during those days.
>
> You are given a int[] power, where the i-th element of power is the power of one creature of level i. The power of your army is the sum of the powers of all its creatures. Return the maximum possible power your army can have after all D days of training are finished.

I'm not able to get the algorithm. It is a Dynamic Programming problem and I'm not able to find any suitable subproblem to which to break it to.

Can anyone provide me with the subproblem I need to consider to solve the problem?

I'd also like to know about the thinking process by which you arrive at the solution.

Comment: Do you know that you can check code submitted by fellow topcoders?

Comment: I came to know that recently. I checked the code, but I was not able to get what subproblem is it that they are considering since they have random names for their variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topcoder includes editorials giving solutions to their problems.

The solution for this is [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=match_editorials&d2=tco08rd2):

> We are given total freedom in how we do the upgrades. When looking for
>   the optimal algorithm, freedom is bad – it gives us too many
>   possibilities to try. How can we constrain the search?
>
> We can decide to be a bit systematic in doing the upgrades. We will
>   start by spending some (possibly zero) days upgrading level 0
>   creatures, then we'll upgrade some level 1 creatures, and so on.
>   Clearly, in this way we'll be able to achieve the optimal total power.
>   (If we have an optimal solution that makes the upgrades in some other
>   order, we can easily rearrange them and do them in our order.)
>
> Now we could easily write a recursive solution that would try all the
>   possibilities. Of course, we would like to memoize the computed values
>   to avoid exponential time complexity. To do this, we need to identify
>   precisely what describes the state of the computation.
>
> Two parameters are obvious: the level L of the creatures we are
>   currently upgrading, and the number D of days left. However, this is
>   not all, there is one more important issue. We might have done some
>   previous upgrades, and thus the current number of level L creatures
>   may be higher than the input value. This difference will be the third,
>   and final, parameter.
>
> There are at most N=50 levels, and at most D=100 days. Obviously, the
>   third parameter can never exceed D. Thus there are at most
>   N*D*D=500,000 states. The time complexity of computing one state is
>   O(D), leading to the overall time complexity O(N*D^3).

```
  long long memo[52][102][102];
  long long counts[52], powers[52];
  int N;

  long long solve(int level, int add, long long upgrades) {
    long long &res = memo[level][add][upgrades];
    if (res >= 0) return res;
    res = 0;
    if (level==N) return res;
    int maxUpgrades = min( upgrades, counts[level]+add );
    for (int now=0; now<=maxUpgrades; now++) {
      long long thisLevel = powers[level] * (counts[level]+add-now);
      long long nextLevels = solve(level+1,now,upgrades-now);
      res = max( res, thisLevel+nextLevels );
    }
    return res;
  }

  long long maximumPower(vector <int> _count, vector <int> _power, int D) {
    memset(memo,-1,sizeof(memo));
    N = _count.size();
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) counts[i] = _count[i];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) powers[i] = _power[i];
    return solve(0,0,D);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this problem has been bugging me for quite a while. By the way, where can I find these editorials? Do they have these for every problem?

Comment: On the topcoder site http://community.topcoder.com/tc use the left hand side box to navigate Competitions->Algorithm->Single Round Matches->Statistics->Editorials

Comment: @deep19 I thought you wanted to know how to solve it not the solution itself !

Comment: actually it's not just the solution, it's the explanation that I needed, and it's explained pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a dp, it is interesting I would love to try it .. I would approach it in this way:

I create an array of the differences of powers between the levels, and then pursue upgrading creatures below that level to gain the maximum power I can add. I think this can be a greedy or knapsack as which ones to upgrade is the critical decision.

edit: well I forgot to mention what you should do with that array: you should sort it to get the sorted indexes .. it will be more of a map actually than an array because you want to shuffle the indexes in the process of sorting so that you can know which levels are the highest difference , positive or negative .. etc

Comment: I've tried both the approaches. It's not greedy, you can easily verify that by simple counter-examples. I've tried to convert it to knapsack, but it's a different case since the number of "weights" is not fixed( you can raise a creature to a new level and the corresponding "weight"

Comment: it is knapsack not greedy sorry ,, you just upgrade the creatures that give you positive power in the upgrade and forget the negative ,, if there is only negative choices you can wait and not train anyone. the value is the difference between the levels.. and the weight will be equal to the number of days you need to train that creature to reach that golden level !

Comment: I don't think that's correct, I tried that approach. See, in knapsack the number of objects remain constant, but in this case your decision changes the number of objects(weights). I'll think about a counter-example to this today.

Comment: Or you can code and test it on topcoder. I'll be surprised if it's correct since I had spend quite some time on converting it to knapsack.